# Change value from api response React

Tags: reactjs, api

From a request call to the marvel API I receive the following

```
       {
        "id": 1011334,
        "name": "3-D Man",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2014-04-29T14:18:17-0400",
        "thumbnail": {
          "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/c/e0/535fecbbb9784",
          "extension": "jpg"
        },
```

How can I change the thumbnail.path to be https instead of HTTP because when I deploy the app I get the warning of mixed content saying it will be change automatically

Comment: you can do like : `yourObject. thumbnail. path.replace("http", "https") `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the value of response after response received. for example:

```
axios.get('/post?ID=12345')
  .then((response) => {
       const modifiedResponse = response.data;
       modifiedResponse.thumbnail.path = 
       modifiedResponse.thumbnail.path.replace("http", "https");
       // I see you tagged react
       this.setState({post: modifiedResponse});
  })
```

Please share more code if it seems my answer is ambiguous.